# PHP: store input variable in session and then echo it on a page is not working

Tags: php

Ok im going to try to explain this:

I have a php page "index.php" where there is a form that posts to a form.php?form=1 that processes the data and then redirects in a split second to a "thank you" page called "paso2.php"

What im trying to do is store the email variable on a session and then echo it on paso2.php

SO i did this at the very top of form.php:

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
// Validation here...
$_SESSION['email_address'] = $_POST['email'];
```

"email" is the name of the email input on index.php

Then on paso2.php i did this at the very top:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();?>
```

and then inside the input on paso2.php i echo the value

```
<input type="text" name="email2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['email_address']);?>" />
```

But its not working! the error i can read inside that value is:

inside the value

```
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: email_address in     <b>/home/gulp1986/public_html/cupon0km.com/paso2.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong to post this value?

Comment: First thing first...can you verify $_SESSION['email_address'] is being set by echoing the value after setting it in index.php?

Comment: Perhaps using "on another page" rather than "on a page" (in your title) would be clearer. Yeah I know, I'm not much help, but I don't see the problem.. Is passing the e-mail as a GET variable a possible alternative?

Comment: not possible to do it by GET becuase it goes to form.php and then to the page i want paso2.php

Comment: everything is set exactly as i described here

Comment: @sebas Are those 2 pages `index.php` and `form.php` using same URL and port?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and/or [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) to view the HTTP headers as your browser goes from index -> form -> paso2, and see if the session  cookie (and id) are being transmitted properly at each stage. Missing vars of this sort are invariably do the session cookie being misconfigured and lost after each stage, leading a new/empty session being created each time.

Comment: I use firebug but im noob and i dont even know how to check the headers :S

Comment: They'll be under the 'Net' tab. You'll see all the requests performed, Clicking the `+` by any of them to open up that particular request will show a Headers tab.

Comment: doing this i found

a350bc043d659158f0b16dc655cb8d91 as SESSION

would u mind taking a look?

http://cupon0km.com/index.php
i also added session_start();
echo session_id(); to the index.php

Comment: Check if that value is the same for the requests on each page. if it changes, then you're getting a brand new session each time, which explains why the variable's "missing" - it's still there, but in a different session.

Comment: cant check it on form.php becuase its a split second it simply processes the data of the form and the redirects to paso2.php

Comment: Yeah, your session is vanishing. Your index/paso pages are coming from "cupon0km.com", while the form is on "clientes.cupon0km.com".

Comment: thats becuase the form is part of a script that is on clientes.cupon0km.com what should i do to fix this? thanks a lot!

Comment: Marc B got it use [session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and set the domain to `.cupon0km.com` (note the dot)

Comment: like this on form.php ??

<?php
$_SESSION['email_address'] = session_get_cookie_params(); 

$rootDomain = '.cupon0km.com'; 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
// Validation here...
$_SESSION['email_address'] = $_POST['email'];

Comment: on form.php this is what i have


<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_set_cookie_params(99999999, '.cupon0km.com');
session_start();
// Validation here...
$_SESSION['email_address'] = $_POST['email'];

Comment: with the code i pasted above its not working, could u please check it?? sorry to be such a pain :S

Comment: it keeps saying the same error

<br /> <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  email_address in <b>/home/gulp1986/public_html/cupon0km.com/paso2.php</b> on line <b>68</b><br />

Comment: As long as you keep getting that error, you've got two different sessions in play. You'll just have to keep investigating your cookie settings until things work.

Answer (score 0):

To start, try adding:

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
```

in your "form.php" file. Assuming your session was started, you should see the corresponding session id.

Also if possible, modify your error reporting to: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to help see if there were any errors associated with the creation of the session.

Comment: ok im gonna add this now what should i do after? i mean what is it for?

Comment: This is part of the process of debugging, especially when you do not have a "smoking-gun" error.

Comment: would u mind taking a look i added that to the index.php but cant figure it out really

http://cupon0km.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

if you make a hidden field in form.php.

```
    <input type='hidden' name='email' value='223218' />
```

then post this form to paso2.php.

```
<form id='form_223218' class='appnitro'  method='post' action='paso2.php'>
```

the session variable should not be empty.

Comment: cant change the way form.php handles the post

Answer (score 0):

A followup to Marc B comment. You need to use do this before each `session_start`

```
<?php
$cookie_params = session_get_cookie_params();

session_set_cookie_params( 
    $cookie_params["lifetime"], 
    $cookie_params["path"], 
    '.cupon0km.com', 
    $cookie_params["secure"], 
    $cookie_params["httponly"] 
);

session_start();
```

You could also put the code above into a file and include it at the top of each page that requires a session.

Some debugging:

In form.php:

comment out the `header('Location: ...')` redirect

In form.php and paso2.php add this at the bottom:

```
echo 'session name' . session_name() . '<br>';
echo 'session id' . session_id() . '<br>';
echo 'cookies <br>'; print_r($_COOKIES);
echo 'session <br>'; print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: nop, its not working used the above code both on form.php and paso2.php same result the error says

<br /> <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  email_address in <b>/home/gulp1986/public_html/cupon0km.com/paso2.php</b> on line <b>68</b><br />

Comment: hey man you are doing some tests, right? im seeing some 1@example emails being posted

Comment: Yea thats me sorry if it caused you any problems. Using chrome inspect element it seems like PHP is creating two session cookies. Is it possible that `session_start` is getting called more than once on any page (maybe an included file)?

Comment: no it was not a problem. and no there is no other session_start and no includes on form

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `session_start()` before everything else. `session_start()` can get a little quirky.

Comment: yes its the very first thing at the very top, this is not the issue